# how to config postgresql to grails application

Tags: grails, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to configure PostgreSQL in a grails application, and I added the `postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar` file to grails app lib folder,and  after that I add `runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-902.jdbc4'` dependencies block in `BuildConfig.groovy`. I am trying to run the application through `run-app`, but it is showing the following error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2012-07-18 11:29:47,573 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp'
->> 1452 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   662 | run      in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLException: No suitable driver
->> 264 | getDriver in java.sql.DriverManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1437 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

This is my `datasource.groovy` file:

```
dataSource {
      pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    username = "postgres"
    password = "password"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/empapp"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: for me "jdbc:postgres" throws errors, but "jdbc:postgresql" works

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't put the jar file in the lib directory if you're using the dependency management in BuildConfig.groovy - it's redundant. But that's unlikely to be the problem. I don't use PostgreSQL much but it appears that the JDBC URL has to use "postgresql", not "postgres":

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/empapp"
```

You can omit the port number if it's the default (5432):

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/empapp"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using PGS database in your development environment, so you should provide the JDBC driver also for the development environment in the BuildConfig.groovy:

```
runtime: 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-902.jdbc4'
```

Comment: `provided` is the wrong scope - that says that it's going to be available outside of Grails. that might be true in prod if it's in the container's shared classpath, but certainly not true in dev. `runtime` (or `compile`) is what you want for a JDBC driver

Comment: Damn, you're right, copied from the project without a check! Bad me ;-)